# Как в java отрицательное десятичное число перевести в двоичное, а затем обратно в отрицательное десятичное?

Tags: java

Допустим

```
int i = -12;
b = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
System.out.println(b);
```

Вывод: 11111111111111111111111111110100

Если попробовать сделать обратную операцию
    p =Integer.parseInt(b, 2);

Выдаёт ошибку:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11111111111111111111111111110100" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583) at p2.P2.main(P2.java:27) C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1 СБОРКА ЗАВЕРШЕНА СО СБОЕМ (общее время: 1 секунда)

Comment: "Если попробовать ... выдаёт ошибку." - Никогда!! не говорите, какою ошибку *оно* выдает.

Comment: Вопрос не в том что бы исправить мой код а в  том что бы объяснить каким способом можно осуществить данное преобразование, код я вставил чтобы мой вопрос прошёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В беззнаковом представлении (которое получилось в результате `toBinaryString`) отрицательное число становится слишком большим, и уже не помещается в int.

Как вариант, можно распарсить число как `long`, а после явно привести к `int`

```java
p = (int) Long.parseLong(b, 2)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помагло

Answer (score 0):

Попрбуйте

```
Integer.parseUnsignedInt(b, 2)
```